# How do I set up a login shell with arguments?

Tags: shell, users, login

I would like to add a user whose sole purpose is provide a "dashboard" for my machine (laptop), without letting them doing anything else (whether it's any useful is debatable, but it's certainly prettier than staring at the tty login). So I tried adding a user:

```
root@localhost:/ # useradd -r -s '/usr/bin/btm --battery' monitor
useradd: Warning: missing or non-executable shell '/usr/bin/btm --battery'
```

By default [`btm`](https://github.com/ClementTsang/bottom) doesn't display battery information, which is something I want given that the machine is a laptop (it is plugged into AC, but I still want it to display battery information).

How can I pass arguments to my login shell? AFAICT, there is no way to display the battery information once the program has started, so I need to pass the flag as part of the shell invocation.

Answer (score 2):

> How can I pass arguments to my login shell?

You can't.

You need to make a new executable that launches your intended executable with the options you want.

Comment: Yeah I figured, I ended up writing a shellscript that invokes the program for me. Thanks.